# Is there any way to read Properties File Excluding its classpath entries?

Tags: java

I have a properties file and i am loading it using Java Properties.

I have some classpath entries in that properties file which are referring to some other properties.

so when i am loading this properties file i am getting classpath file properties key with the same object.

Is there any way to read Properties File Excluding its classpath entries?

example1.properties

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
[classpath:/example2.properties]
```

example2.properties

```
key3 = value3
```

This is how i am loading file in java

```
private void loadProperties()
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    File file= new File( "example1.properties");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream( file);
    props.load( inputStream );
    Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entries = props.entrySet();
    for( Entry<Object, Object> entry : entries )
    {
        System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

actual output :

```
key1 -> value1
key2 -> value2
key3 -> value3
```

**i wanted to exclude example2.properties file while loading example1.properties**

Comment: How is your project set up? I mean, is it maven, ant, gradle or just an [ide] like project ?

Comment: Why don't you use an auxiliary properties file, named `index.properties` for instance, where you would place all the other properties file that you reference. That way you would use it just for that, removing the necessity of having those properties in your `example1.properties`.

Comment: @ariberio My project structure will not allow me to do that.